# Intermittent persistence of Clipboard data after app exits

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a simple C# console app that copies a line of text to the clipboard, which is persisted after the app exits. I'm seeing intermittent behavior where sometimes the text will be on the clipboard after the app runs, but sometimes it will not - if I open notepad and hit Ctrl-V, I will sometimes get the "testing" message pasted, but other times, nothing gets pasted. However, the clipboard text is always accessible within the app where I call the GetText method.

I have found that if I attempt to Ctrl-V paste the text before closing the console app's window, then the text generally gets pasted and persisted consistently, but if I do not then it seems random as to whether or not the text will remain on the clipboard. For example, after a successful paste just now using the method of pasting before the console window closes, I ran the app again - it pasted successfully without the console window open; I ran it a third time - the clipboard is blank when I try to paste.

See my code below - I have the Target Framework set as .NET 4.8 and the code compiles and runs without any errors or warnings.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
//using System.Windows.Forms; //Produced the same issue

namespace ClipboardTest
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            //Clipboard.SetText("Test text", TextDataFormat.Text); //Also didn't work consistently
            Clipboard.SetDataObject("testing", true);
            Console.WriteLine(Clipboard.GetText());

        }
    }
}
```

Things I have tried:

- Using the boolean flag of SetDataObject meant to persist the data after the app exits
- Using the SetText method instead
- Using System.Windows.Forms instead of System.Windows

Supplementary info:

- I'm on Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
  Version 16.9.4

Answer (score 1):

Use [SetText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.settext?view=net-5.0) or construct a fully configured [DataObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dataobject?view=net-5.0). Which is what `SetText` does. By calling `SetDataObject` without a format you put a DataObject in the Clipboard without any hint of what it contains. If an application can't find a format it understands, it won't paste anything. That's why you can paste an image into Paint but not Notepad.

**How the clipboard works**

Notice that the parameter is called `copy` in the source code, not `persist`.

The Clipboard isn't a persistence mechanism, it's an indirect Inter-Process Communication (IPC) mechanism meant to exchange document-like data between two applications. For that to work, the applications must agree on the format of the data.

This is done by storing the data in various formats. When you copy something from eg Word, the application stores the data in several formats, so that other applications can find a format they understand.

When you paste something, the target application checks the Clipboard for a format it understands. Most applications will simply ignore data in formats they don't understand.

*When both applications are active* it's possible to communicate through the Clipboard without actually storing all the data there.

**What is actually going on**

If you check the [source code of SetText](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Clipboard.cs,365) you'll see it does more than just save the text. It [creates a DataObject](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Clipboard.cs,888) whose format is `TextDataFormat.UnicodeText`.

```
    public static void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (text == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
        }

        SetText(text, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the text data to Clipboard.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetText(string text, TextDataFormat format)
    {
        if (text == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
        }

        if (!DataFormats.IsValidTextDataFormat(format))
        {
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("format", (int)format, typeof(TextDataFormat));
        }

        SetDataInternal(DataFormats.ConvertToDataFormats(format), text);
    }
```

Finally, [it calls](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Clipboard.cs,905):

```
    private static void SetDataInternal(string format, object data)
    {
        IDataObject dataObject;
        bool autoConvert;

        if (IsDataFormatAutoConvert(format))
        {
            autoConvert = true;
        }
        else
        {
            autoConvert = false;
        }

        dataObject = new DataObject();
        dataObject.SetData(format, data, autoConvert);

        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, /*copy*/true);
    }
```

[SetDataObject](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Clipboard.cs,552) in turn will check whether `data` is a DataObject/IComDataObject, otherwise it will just put the `data` value inside a new `DataObject` and hope for the best.

```
if (data is DataObject)
{
    dataObject = (DataObject)data;
}
else if (data is IComDataObject)
{
    SecurityHelper.DemandUnmanagedCode();
    dataObject = (IComDataObject)data;
}
else
{
    dataObject = new DataObject(data);
}
```